How can we change one of the set of the optimization problem modeled in OPL using python and store the results for every set
I have formulated an optimization problem in OPL Cplex.
The objective of the problem -
minimize   sum(n in Node, t in Time)(100000Wi[n](pd[n][t]))
subjected to
System Constraints
**One of the constraints of the optimization problem **
  forall (n in Damage_Node){
    forall (t in Time){
      Status[n][t]<= Status[n][t+1];
    }
  }

This constraint requires the set Damage_Node to solve the optimization problem. In my problem, I want to solve the same problem for multiple time with different set of Damage_Node. For example, the set of Damage_Node for five cases are given below:
1   {5,9,11,21,23,25,29}
2   {4,7,1,8,34}  
3   {37,16,28,11,19,5}
4   {12,22,6,15,2,6}
5   {10,13,18,1,24}

Therefore, I have written one code in Python that will solve the same optimization problem for all five cases just by changing the set Damage_Node. This set I want to give input to OPL model through python
The code that I have written in python is given below. I have tried this code for one case only. please suggest me code in python in which I can find out the solution of the optimization problem by changing the input Damage_Nodes and store the solution for each case.
The python code is given below
from doopl.factory import create_opl_model

Damage_Nodes = [
({5,9,11,21,23,25,29}),  
]

model_path = "C:/User/Vandana/opl/repair/repair.mod"

with create_opl_model(model=model_path) as opl:

opl.set_input("damage_Nodes", Damage_Nodes)

opl.run()

decision_vars = opl.get_decision_variables()

for var in decision_vars:
    print(f"{var} = {decision_vars[var]}")

objective_value = opl.get_objective_value()
print("Objective value:", objective_value)`

As I have mentioned that the set Damage_Nodes is different for different case. Therefore, in OPL model the set Damage_Nodes should be empty and through python code we will provide the set of damage node to the OPL model
The code for the OPL model to receive input from Python is provided below.
tuple damage_Node {
int scenario;
{int} value;
}


{damage_Node} damage_Nodes = ...;

But I think this is not the correct way to give input the OPL model using python
Suggest me code in python to feed input set (Damage_Node) of one scenario at a time and to store the result for that case in python by solving the optimization problem modeled in OPL CPLEX. And in similar manner we can solve the optimization problem for other four cases and finally we are able to store the result in python for all five cases. Suggest the changes that we need to do in OPL model which can read input (set of Damage_Node) from python and give the solution to python.
